# Visual Studio 2017 .net core project give Restoring NuGet packages for bootstrapper error when adding wcf endpoint

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0, nuget-package-restore

With Visual Studio 2017 preview (latest version of VS 2017 Professional), in ASP.Net Core 2.0 project, I am trying to add a WCF service via Connected Services, and it gives the below error.

My teammate has the same project and it works on his computer but gives the below error on my pc. I cleaned the project, rebuild but the error is not fixed. What should I do? Is that error about WCF, or NuGet? I deleted and reinstalled NuGet but the error still occurs.

> Importing web service metadata ... Number of service endpoints found:
>   1 Restoring NuGet packages ... Building solution ... Scaffolding
>   service reference code ... Restoring NuGet packages for bootstrapper
>   ... Error:Error: Restoring packages for
>   C:\Users\MSefer\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2017_Nov_13_19_03_33\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcUtilBootstrapper.csproj...
>   C:\Users\MSefer\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2017_Nov_13_19_03_33\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcUtilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : warning NU1603: dotnet-svcutil 1.0.0-preview-11010-660 depends on
>   System.Collections.Specialized (>= 4.0.1) but
>   System.Collections.Specialized 4.0.1 was not found. An approximate
>   best match of System.Collections.Specialized 4.3.0 was resolved.
>   C:\Users\MSefer\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2017_Nov_13_19_03_33\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcUtilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : warning NU1603: dotnet-svcutil 1.0.0-preview-11010-660 depends on
>   System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter (>= 4.1.0) but
>   System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter 4.1.0 was not found. An
>   approximate best match of System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter 4.3.0
>   was resolved.
>   C:\Users\MSefer\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2017_Nov_13_19_03_33\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcUtilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : warning NU1603: dotnet-svcutil 1.0.0-preview-11010-660 depends on
>   System.Linq.Expressions (>= 4.1.1) but System.Linq.Expressions 4.1.1
>   was not found. An approximate best match of System.Linq.Expressions
>   4.3.0 was resolved. C:\Users\MSefer\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2017_Nov_13_19_03_33\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcUtilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1102: Unable to find package
>   System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync with version (>= 4.0.11)
>   C:\Users\MSefer\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2017_Nov_13_19_03_33\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcUtilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1102:   - Found 1 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Offline Packages [ Nearest version: 4.0.10 ]
>   C:\Users\MSefer\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2017_Nov_13_19_03_33\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcUtilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1102:   - Found 0 version(s) in SvcUtilLocalFeed
>   C:\Users\MSefer\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2017_Nov_13_19_03_33\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcUtilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1101: Unable to find package System.Data.Common. No packages
>   exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline
>   Packages, SvcUtilLocalFeed
>   C:\Users\MSefer\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2017_Nov_13_19_03_33\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcUtilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1101: Unable to find package System.Net.WebSockets. No
>   packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Offline Packages, SvcUtilLocalFeed
>   C:\Users\MSefer\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2017_Nov_13_19_03_33\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcUtilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1101: Unable to find package System.Net.WebSockets.Client.
>   No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Offline Packages, SvcUtilLocalFeed
>   C:\Users\MSefer\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2017_Nov_13_19_03_33\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcUtilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1101: Unable to find package System.Private.ServiceModel. No
>   packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Offline Packages, SvcUtilLocalFeed
>   C:\Users\MSefer\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2017_Nov_13_19_03_33\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcUtilBootstrapper.csproj
>   : error NU1101: Unable to find package System.ServiceModel.Primitives.
>   No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Offline Packages, SvcUtilLocalFeed   Generating MSBuild file
>   C:\Users\MSefer\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2017_Nov_13_19_03_33\svcutil_bootstrap\obj\SvcUtilBootstrapper.csproj.nuget.g.props.   Generating MSBuild file
>   C:\Users\MSefer\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2017_Nov_13_19_03_33\svcutil_bootstrap\obj\SvcUtilBootstrapper.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
>   Restore failed in 3,32 sec for
>   C:\Users\MSefer\AppData\Local\Temp\WCFConnectedService\2017_Nov_13_19_03_33\svcutil_bootstrap\SvcUtilBootstrapper.csproj.
>   An error occurred while bootstrapping svcutil. This usually happens
>   when processing references.  You might be able to work around this
>   problem by not providing reference parameters, and manually removing
>   any types redefined in the generated proxy code. Error:An unknown
>   error occurred while invoking the service metadata component. Failed
>   to generate service reference.

Comment: Can you try to do a clean solution and then perform nuget restore. Before nuget restore try clearing your nuget cache.  You can list the local caches with this command:

nuget locals all -list
You can clear all caches with this command:

nuget locals all -clear

Comment: What target framework are you using? If you are going to use WCF it cannot be a Core framework. WCF is not supported with .Net Core.

Comment: @R.Richards my project asp.net core 2.0 my target .net core 2.0...Wcf is another.I just want to use their wcf in my project.The same wcf endpoint url work in my friend pc in .net core 2.0 project

Answer (score 1):

I change package source(tools->nuget package manager->manage nuget package
...)  with nuget.org instead of visual studio package and it works

via:
http://yazilimsozluk.com/visual-studio-2017-net-core-projesine-wcf-eklemede-restoring-nuget-packages-for-bootstrapper-errorerror-restoring-packages-hatasi